# EditText & Button Not Showing Up Above ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-button

I have this fragment that contains a list view. I now added a button and an edit text to use as a search bar. The application runs fine and shows the list view, but I don't see the button or the edit text anywhere. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, here is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".BookListFragment"/>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchBox"
        android:layout_width="241dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="113dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="639dp"
        android:autofillHints="@string/search"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="279dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="646dp"
        android:text="@string/search" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've the below issues

- You've two root layouts: ListView & RelativeLayout, so I wrapped the
  ListView within the RelativeLayout to keep a single top root view.
- Your RelativeLayout has width & height of 0dp, so its content won't
  display
- Fixed ListView under the Button & EditText using
  `android:layout_alignParentBottom`
- Removed too big margin at the bottom from the Button & the EditText
  Removed
- Removed unusable Constraint that are related to ConstraintLayout

try using the below layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    tools:context=".BookListFragment">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchBox"
        android:layout_width="241dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="113dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="113dp"
        android:autofillHints="@string/search"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="279dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/search" />


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchBox"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView has a match-parent Height, in this case it will fill all the screen. When you want to put many thins in the screen you should use a Layout manager to organize it. try something like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchBox"
            android:layout_width="241dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="113dp"
            android:autofillHints="search"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="279dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="search" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    
    
    <!-- Your List View Come Here -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It may works but is not the best way to make this layout. you should see a little more about Layout Xml [Official Description](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout)